# Shell script: exporting variables from one shell script to another shell script not working using "source/export"

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to call variables from one shell script to other. I used "source" and "export" but none are doing the job. A mention, that it is CGI bash script. And in the bash script there is also "" HTML links to other CGI scripts. For example - I am doing like this;

script1: test1.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
....
export XX="1"
export YY="2"
"echo "<p><a href = "/path/to/second/CGI/script/test4.sh" >to choose click</a></p>"
```

script 2: test4.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<form action="/path/to/third/CGI/script/test5.sh" method="GET">"
echo "</form>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
echo "XX =$XX"
```

script 3: test5.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
#source <(grep '^export .*=' test1.sh)
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "XX = $XX"
```

but it gives me nothing in "test5.sh"

So, I called "test4.sh" from "test1.sh" using HTML and exported all variables of "test1.sh" to "test4.sh" as shown above. All the variables are exported well to "test4.sh" but the variables are not getting exported to "test5.sh" from "test1.sh". I want to use the variables of "test1.sh" in "test5.sh" also. Likewise, I have other bash scripts in the same directory, in which I would like to export the variables and their values from "test1.sh". Can you please let me know how can I do it? I tried "source" like above in "test5.sh" but it does not work. Please let me know if you need more information on this.

Note: I don't want to directly call "test5.sh" from "test1.sh" using "bash test5.sh"or "./test5.sh" in "test1.sh" script due to programming structure. The sequence has to be "test1.sh exports variables to test4.sh and test5.sh"

Thank you so much! DK

Comment: Please make sure your code actually runs, as given in the question, and exhibits only the error your question is actually about.

Comment: That said -- exported variables **only** go from parent to child. That's a hard constraint and true across all languages running on UNIX systems, not at all shell-specific.

Comment: BTW, `<()`, as used in `<(grep '^export .*=' test1.sh)`, is a bash extension. It isn't supported in `/bin/sh` at all; and what you're doing isn't exporting your variables from running `test1.sh`, but rather grepping the source code of `test1.sh` without running it, and then executing only the lines selected by `grep`. You can do that, but I wouldn't describe what it does as "exporting" variables from one to the other in any meaningful sense.

Comment: (Related: Using the `#!/bin/sh` shebang means your scripts get run with `sh`, not `bash`, so you shouldn't be using the `bash` tag on your related StackOverflow questions; even if `sh` is a link to `bash` on your system, it runs in POSIX compatibility mode when invoked under that name).

Comment: Thanks Charles Duffy! Could you please let me know how can I achieve the goal here, i.e. get the variables of "test1.sh" to be used in "test5.sh".

Comment: Frankly, my best answer is "don't". Running `grep` has a performance penalty, and there's no good reason to pay it -- you'd be better off moving the variables off to a separate file and sourcing in that file from everywhere it's needed.

Comment: Another thing that's a bashism, by the way, is `source` -- to be compatible to `/bin/sh`, you should be using the dot keyword: `. vars` (if `vars` is the file where they're defined).

Comment: Thanks much! I am a beginner in shell scripting. I would really appreciate if you could please tell me what exactly you mean "moving the variables off to a separate file and sourcing in that file from everywhere it's needed." Could you please tell me using the example of variables here in this script. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'll do the grunt work for Charles:

script0: vars.sh

```
XX="1"
YY="2"
```

script1: test1.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

## If some content in this file not shown in the example needs the values, then:
. /path/to/vars.sh

## These lines are no longer needed
# export XX="1"
# export YY="2"

echo '<p><a href = "/path/to/second/CGI/script/test4.sh" >to choose click</a></p>'
```

script 2: test4.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
. /path/to/vars.sh

cat <<"END_HTML"
Content-type: text/html

<html>
<body>
<form action="/path/to/third/CGI/script/test5.sh" method="GET">
</form>
<div>XX =$XX</div>
</body>
</html>
END_HTML
```

script 3: test5.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
. /path/to/vars/sh

echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""
echo "XX = $XX"
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried doing the above, but it's not exporting the variables. May be if I clear these doubts below I will get to a solution: a) In script1.sh, I have values like this; "xx=$(cat $d | head -n 1)" & "yy=$(sed -n '3p' < $hk)", so, I need to have these values in "script1.sh". As commented for "script1.sh", do I really need to remove all variables from "script1.sh" and put in "vars.sh"? The script is long about 300 lines with for and while loops, so can't paste here b) Also by doing this the variables do not get exported even to the child script "script4.sh". Thanks much!

Comment: The variables only need to be exported if any external program you call also need them. Otherwise, if they're only being used in the script that sources the file, you don't need to export them.

Comment: Thanks Glenn! but, yes I need to export the variables to script4 and script5. And the above procedure is not working. Please let me know if you have any idea on what could be done to export and have the variables values from script1 to both scripts (script4 and script5). I have tried the above procedure, but unsuccessful.

Comment: You don't need to `export` the variables because script4 and script5 actually source them, so they are local to those shell instances. I can't really advise you further without seeing your code.

Comment: Thanks much! It works :) after I changed the shebang line to "bash" and not "sh". However, this example works but the main task that I want to work isn't. I am following the same as here but it's not working. So, I have variables in "vars.sh"; example of variables are --namr="$(echo "${dj}" | awk -F/ '{print $NF}')",
line1="$(cat "$d" | head -n 1)",
tyu="$(echo "$line1" | awk '{print "$5}')",
drf="$(ls | grep -E "modified.*${namr}.*blast-aligned-part.*mutated.pir")", hk="$hk",
thr="$(sed -n '3p' < $hk)"----; is there problem in having these variables in "vars.sh" to be exported?